# curl not connecting, but I can visit it in my browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I am unsure what this is, but when I do:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"foo":"bar"}' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Token bdcaf10129ba8ad968c03c6083898bf8c426f749d4e9a14d58e4ef02bfe1c217'
'http://api.site.local.com:4000/internal/application/v1/users'

 # New lines in above request are only there for readability.

curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.site.local.com port 4000: Connection refused
```

But if I go to:

http://api.site.local.com:4000/internal/application/v1/users

It works, I mean I get an error that there is no index action, but none the less the actual route exists and is working.

So why is the browser saying yes, but curl is saying no?

I mean my test:

```
it "should return 200 for a user being published" do
VCR.use_cassette 'publisher/publish_user_200' do
  site = double(
    'site',
    :site_api_url => YAML.load(File.read('config/application.yml'))['APPLICATION_URL'].to_s,
    :site_api_key => YAML.load(File.read('config/application.yml'))['APPLICATION_KEY'].to_s
  )

  expect(
    BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.publish(
      site,
      {
        first_name: 'adsadsad', user_name: 'sasdasdasdsa'  ,
        email: 'asdassad@sample.com', auth_token: 'asdsadasdasdsa'
      }
    ).code
  ).to eql 200
end
```

returns a 0, meaning it could not connect. Am I doing something wrong I don't know about?

**Note:** The application key and url from the applications.yml file are the same as the values in the curl request.

Comment: It is not even making a connection. What does `nslookup api.site.local.com` give?

Comment: What does you're route look like? If you go to a browser, you're executing the GET method but in curl you're using POST. Are both defined?